# How to perform a count in a loop

Tags: php, html

```
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

?>

<div class='lt-container'>
<p><strong>QUESTION <span id="quesnum"></span>:</strong></p>
</div>


<?php

}

?>
```

In code above I have a while loop where it displays `QUESTION :`. Now what I want to do is in between `QUESTION` and `:` I want to include a count number so that for every time `QUESTION` appears, it contains a count number next to it as like below:

```
QUESTION 1:


QUESTION 2:


QUESTION 3:

...
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable and increment it in foreach.

Like:

```
$s = 1;
foreach($value as $text) {
echo "Question #".$s." :".$text;
$s++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a variable and increment it

```
$i=1;
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

?>

<div class='lt-container'>
<p><strong>QUESTION <span id="quesnum"><? echo $i; ?></span>:</strong></p>
</div>


<?php
$i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

?>

<div class='lt-container'>
<p><strong>QUESTION <span id="quesnum"><?php echo $count++; $></span>:</strong></p>
</div>


<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
$i=$i+1;
?>
<div class='lt-container'>
<p><strong>QUESTION <span id="quesnum"></span>:<?php echo $i;?></strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qno = 1;
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

?>

<div class='lt-container'>
    <p><strong>QUESTION <span id="quesnum"></span>:</strong><?php echo $qno?></p>
</div>


<?php
$qno++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way too,

```
$countArray = array();
foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
$countArray[] = $key;
}
count($countArray) or sizeOf()
```

(OR) Directly you can get without for loop itself like the below

```
count($arrQuestionId)
```